# Compiling LaTeX from notepad++ and opening with sumatra. ForwardSearch doesn't work if file path contains umlauts

Tags: batch-file, latex, notepad++, dde, nppexec

I've had this small problem for quite some time now and I haven't been able to find a solution even after excessive googling. 
In [this guide](http://johnbruer.com/2013/05/21/latex-editing-using-notepad/) it is described how LaTeX can be written and compiled using npp++ and nppExec together with SumatraPDF.

Through some clever scripts and the use of DDE commands (through [CMCDDE.exe](http://www.istri.fr/spip/zip/CMCDDE.zip)), it is even possible to use sumatra's ForwardSearch to jump back and forth from the .tex to the .pdf. Everything works great, **unless** the path to the .tex file contains a character that's not in the English alphabet (for example åäö).

The CMCDDE command then fails because the path sent to sumatra's ForwardSearch reads (for example) `C:\†„”` instead of `C:\åäö`. This has to be an encoding issue and I haven't been able to find a working solution.

So, if I have this .tex file `C:\åäö\MWE.tex` with

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

it won't open correctly when using the batch script described in the [link above](http://johnbruer.com/2013/05/21/latex-editing-using-notepad/). These are the problematic batch file lines:

```
::Writes the commands that are to be executed using CMCDDE.exe (through cmcdde.tmp)
echo SUMATRA>"%~dp1build\cmcdde.tmp"
::%~dp1build transforms into C:\åäö\build for the MWE
echo control>>"%~dp1build\cmcdde.tmp"
echo [ForwardSearch("%~dp1build\%~n1.pdf", "%~f1", %2, 0, 0, 0)]>>"%~dp1build\cmcdde.tmp" 
:: This gives the following line in cmcdde.tmp: [ForwardSearch("P:\Documents\†„”\build\MWE.pdf", "P:\Documents\†„”\MWE.tex", 3, 0, 0, 0)] (in ANSI encoding)

"P:\Documents\localtexmf\cmcdde.exe" @"%~dp1build\cmcdde.txt"
:: This fails because the path P:\Documents\†„”\build doesn't exist (P:\Documents\åäö\build does)
```

Ideas I've had and tried:

- I tried changing the encoding by using chcp 65001 and chcp 865 but
  haven't been able to get it to work.
- I have also tried using a
  [search and replace
  script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087463/batch-script-to-find-and-replace-a-string-in-text-file-within-a-minute-for-files) to go through the cmcdde.tmp file before executing it but it didn't
  succeed (I'm not sure which signs I should search for to exchange for
  åäö, †„” or Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶ or ├Ñ├ñ├Â or other?)
- I have also tried putting
  cmd /c or cmd /a /c before the echo commands (as sort of described
  [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/npp-plugins/discussion/672146/thread/87237314/))
  but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Please let me know <s>if something</s> which parts of the question that are unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution. Turns out using the code page 1252 solves the problem.

So putting `chcp 1252` at the beginning of the batch file is the solution. However, if you're using other none standard characters than me (other then the ones in the nordic alphabet), I'm guessing you might need another code page.

Experiment and test different ones until you get it working.